# cannot convert ‘std::function<void*()>’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm new to using the `<functional>` library, so bear with me. The following code is failing to compile, with this error:

> error: cannot convert `std::function<void*()>` to `void* (*)(void*)` for argument `3` to `int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)`.

I don't have to use `<functional>` in my code, but I figured I'd see if there's a solution before giving up and using standard function pointers.

Here's what I have:

```
vector< function< void*() > > signals;
vector< pthread_t > signal_threads;

// Master Signal Handler
void MasterSignalHandler()
{
    for (auto & signal_handler : signals)
    {
        // Create a thread handle
        pthread_t thread_handle;

        // Spawn a thread for the signal handler
        if (0 == pthread_create(&thread_handle, NULL, signal_handler, NULL))
        {
                // Push back the thread handle to the signal thread vector
                signal_threads.push_back(thread_handle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't rather use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)?

Comment: The error is accurate, `std::function` is not a supported parameter for [`pthread_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html).  It weould be accepted by [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) though, which would also work outside of a POSIX environment.

Comment: Thanks guys! std::thread is what I needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose there are two kinds of answers I can give to this one: I can show you the proper way to do what you're trying to do (start a thread) in C++, or I can show you how to squeeze a `std::function` object into `pthread_create`. The first has more practical value, while the second serves to explain how `pthread_create` handles context. There's value in both, so:

## 1. How to call a `std::function<void*()>` object in a new thread

Since C++11, the standard library contains facilities for multithreading. In your case, we have a function with a return value, so the task is to

1. Call the function asynchronously, and
2. Get the return value when we need it.

The most straightforward way to do this is to use `std::async` and `std::future<void*>`. Consider this simple example to make **one** call asynchronously:

```
std::function<void*()> f; // the function to call

// Call f asynchronously. It is possible to omit the std::launch::async
// parameter, in which case it is up to the implementation when or even 
// if a thread is spawned to make the call.
// The future object represents a handle to the void* value that f will
// eventually return (i.e., the future value).
std::future<void*> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, f);

// Do some other stuff while we're waiting

// get f's return value. This will wait if the thread is not yet finished.
void *value_returned_by_f = fut.get();
```

In your case, you want to call more than one function and get the return values at your leisure, so you want to store the `std::future<void*>` objects somewhere. As luck would have it, the structure of your code can be mostly preserved:

```
vector<function<void*()>> signals;
vector<std::future<void*>> signal_futures;

// Master Signal Handler
void MasterSignalHandler()
{
    for (auto & signal_handler : signals)
    {
        signal_futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, signal_handler));
    }
}
```

You can then later retrieve the return values from `signal_futures` at your leisure.

Note that if the functions did not return values, you could use `std::thread` instead of `std::future`:

```
vector<function<void()>> signals;
vector<std::thread> signal_threads;

// Master Signal Handler
void MasterSignalHandler()
{
    for (auto & signal_handler : signals)
    {
        signal_threads.emplace_back(signal_handler);
    }
}
```

Instead of `.get()`ing the result from the future, you would then eventually `.join()` the threads. Using `std::future<void>` would also work, so this is mostly a matter of taste, really.

## 2. How to force `std::function<void*()>` into `pthread_create`

We've just discussed the sensible way to go about the problem, now let's take a look at the dirty bits. The reason your original code does not compile is that `pthread_create` expects a memory address pointing to a function (i.e., machine code) that it can execute, and that `signal_handler` is not such a memory address but a complex object with state. `pthread_create` cannot handle it.

However: if you look carefully, you will note that the function `pthread_create` expects takes a `void*` argument, and that `pthread_create` takes a `void*` argument later in its signature -- this latter argument is passed to the function when the thread is started. If we really wanted to, we could use this mechanism, and in fact on POSIX-based systems, `std::thread` will generally do exactly this for you. For example:

```
void *thread_stub(void *context) {
  // context is static_cast<void*>(&f) below. We reverse the cast to
  // void* and call the std::function object.
  std::function<void*()> &func = *static_cast<std::function<void*()>*>(context);
  return func();
}

// ...

std::function<void*()> f;

// IMPORTANT: Used this way, f must not go out of scope while the thread
// is running because the thread holds a pointer to it!
pthread_t thread_handle;
pthread_create(&thread_handle, NULL, thread_stub, &f);
```

**Note that I do not recommend doing it this way.** It is ugly, and it has the problem mentioned in the comment above. `std::thread` and its associated classes in the standard library solve all these issues for you, so there's no need to reinvent this particular wheel.

Comment: Your implementation of 1 is EXACTLY what I needed, and very elegant. I also appreciate the detailed explanation so I can learn, and not just CTRL-C, CTRL-V.